# Does an rvalue keep its "status" when a const reference parameter binds to it?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, pass-by-const-reference

Let `T` be an arbitrary type. Consider a function that takes a `const` [lvalue] reference:

```cpp
void f(const T &obj);
```

Suppose that this function internally makes a call to another function, which has an rvalue reference overload:

```cpp
void g(T &&obj);
```

If we pass an rvalue to `f`, will the rvalue reference overload of `g` be called, or will it fail to do so since it has been "converted"/bound to a `const` lvalue reference?

Similarly, if `f` called a function that takes an instance of `T` by value,

```cpp
void h(T obj);
```

and `T` has a move constructor, (i.e. `T(T &&);`), will the move constructor be called, or will the copy constructor be called?

In conclusion, if we wanted to ensure that, when calling `f` on an rvalue, the rvalue reference is passed around keeping its rvalue "status", would we necessarily have to provide an rvalue reference overload for `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the name of a reference as an expression, that expression is always an lvalue. No matter if it's a lvalue reference or an rvalue reference. It also doesn't matter if the reference was initialized with an lvalue or an rvalue.

```
int &&x = 1;
f(x); // Here `x` is lvalue.
```

So in `void f(const T &obj) {...}`, `obj` is always an lvalue, regardless of what you pass as an argument.

Also note that value category is determined at compile time. Since `f` is not a template, value category of every expression in it can't depend on arguments you pass.

Thus:

> If we pass an rvalue to `f`, will the rvalue reference overload of `g` be called

No.

> if `f` called a function that takes an instance of `T` by value, `void h(T obj);` and `T` has a move constructor, (i.e. `T(T &&);`), will the move constructor be called

No.

> In conclusion, if we wanted to ensure that, when calling `f` on an rvalue, the rvalue reference is passed around keeping its rvalue "status", would we necessarily have to provide an rvalue reference overload for `f`?

Providing an overload is one option. Note that in this case you have to explicitly call `std::move` in the rvalue overload.

Another option is using *forwarding references*, as Nicol Bolas suggests:

```
template <typename T> void f(T &&t)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Here, `std::forward` essentially acts as a 'conditional `move`'. It moves `t` if an rvalue was passed to it, and does nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Value categories are applied to *expressions*, not objects. `obj` in `f` is an lvalue expression, and will therefore be treated as such. Note that `obj` in `g` is *also* an lvalue expression; if the expression is a name for an object, then it's an lvalue.

The ability you're talking about is exactly why forwarding references exist: so that the copy/move aspects of an argument expression's value category can be preserved through function calls. `f` would have to become a template of the form `template<typename T> void f(T&& t);`, and you would have to use `std::forward` when passing it to `g`.